# jQuery UI modal dialog and JSFiddle - how to remove scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, jsfiddle

I have created a simple example of using jQuery UI Dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/RTADa/

```
<div id="message">
    This is a test
</div>

$(function(){

    $("#message").dialog({modal: true, resizable: false});

});
```

In IE9, IE10, and Chrome I'm getting vertical and horizontal scrollbars. Is this a bug in jQuery UI or I have to add some additional CSS to remove them?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried viewing your fiddle on Chrome 25.0.1, FF 17.0.1, and IE9. No scrollbars.

Comment: Scrollbars where? IN the dialog r the main window?

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://i50.tinypic.com/154czdi.jpg, using Chrome 25.0.1364.152 m

Comment: Here is how I see the page in IE9: https://browserling.com/queue?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FRTADa%2F&browser=explorer&version=9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the body overflow hidden

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RTADa/1/)

```
body{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Any idea why jQuery UI is not doing this automatically?

Comment: No, don't know why, maybe is a little bug